# error in returning jsx tags as a return statement : Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getTractorNumber'"

What i'm trying to do is to return `` <Link to ={`/assign-tractor/${user_id}`}> Assign Tractor </Link> `` to be rendered if the `tractor-id` is null, Otherwise return `` <Link to ={`/tractor-details/${tractorId}`}>{this.tractorNumber}</Link> ``

how can I fix my code to make it do what I want it to do? Is there a better way to approach this?

Note: I'm new to React and JavaScript, so a lot of the syntax and language nuances are not very familiar. Please keep the answer as basic as possible so it is easily digested.

```js
import React, {Link, useState,Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './assignment-table.css';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';


class AssignmentTable extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users : [],
      isLoggeIn: false,
      tractorNumber:"",
      orderNumber:""
    }
    this.getTractorNumber = this.getTractorNumber.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/project/user/drivers`)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data[0])
      this.setState({ users: response.data })
    })
    .catch( err => console.log(err));

  }

  async getTractorNumber(tractorId, user_id){

    if(tractorId == null || tractorId ==undefined){
      return <Link to ={`/assign-tractor/${user_id}`}> Assign Tractor </Link>;
    }
    else{
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/project/tractor/${tractorId}`)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ tractorNumber: response.data.tractorNumber })
      });

     return <Link to ={`/tractor-details/${tractorId}`}>{this.state.tractorNumber}</Link>;
    }

   }

  render(){

    let users = this.state.users? this.state.users.map((item, key) => {
      return (
            <tr>
              <td key = {key}>{item.firstName}  {item.lastName}</td>
               <td>{this.getTractorNumber(item.tractor, item.id)}</td>
            </tr>
            )
    }) : "No Avilable Driver";

    return (
<table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Driver Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Tractor</th>
      <th scope="col">Order</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {users}
  </tbody>
</table>
)};

}
export default withRouter (AssignmentTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues with your code:

I believe the error is happening because `getTractorNumber` isn't correctly bound to `this`. You need to bind it in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.getTractorNumber = this.getTractorNumber.bind(this);
}
```

Separately, it's not a good idea to call either your API or `setState` in `render`. You should move that piece to `componentDidMount` along with your other API call.

You reference `this.tractorNumber` in `getTractorNumber`, but that class variable doesn't seem to exist. I think you meant `this.state.tractorNumber`?

Finally, I'm not aware of React exporting a `Link` component. Pretty sure you should be importing that from `react-router-dom`.

Comment: ok I made some of the changes but i'm not sure how to implement the others. I am already importing ```Link``` in the component. how would you re-write the ```componentDidMount ``` and ```render``` methods so it has all the Api calls nd ```setState``` method in the right place ?